# UISwitch not deallocating

Tags: swift, swift3, uiswitch, persistent

This is a repost of my question before but because of too many edit's and I've simplified my examples, I thought it would be more clear if I create a new question instead of re-edit the questions multiple times.

**PROBLEM:**
`UISwitch` object somehow doesn't deallocate even when nothing has been done with it.

---

**PROJECT:**
There are only two view controllers. VC1 and VC2. VC1 has one button to present VC2. VC2 contains one button to dismiss itself and a property of a custom `UISwitch`, `UILabel` and a `UIStepper`.

**VC1:**

```
class VC1: UIViewController {

    let button = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(button)

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(open), for: .touchUpInside)

        // Some auto layout (not relevant to the question)
    }

    func open() { present(VC2(), animated: true) }
}
```

**VC2:**

```
class VC2: UIViewController {

    let button = UIButton()

    let shifty = CustomSwitch()    // Note: nothing has been done with this
    let labels = CustomLabels()
    let steppy = CustomSteppy()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(button)

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(close), for: .touchUpInside)

        // Some auto layout (not relevant to the question)
    }

    func close() { dismiss(animated: true) }
}
```

**SUBCLASSES:**

```
class CustomSwitch: UISwitch  { deinit { print("Switch has been deinitialized") } }
class CustomLabels: UILabel   { deinit { print("Labels has been deinitialized") } }
class CustomSteppy: UIStepper { deinit { print("Steppy has been deinitialized") } }
```

The only reason I created these subclasses is so I could track them easier in the profiler. The same happens even when I don't subclass `UISwitch`.

**EDIT:**
I've added a `deinit` to the subclasses and both the `UILabel` as well as the `UIStepper` are showing the message:

```
Labels has been deinitialized
Steppy has been deinitialized
```

So it doesn't seem the `UISwitch` is getting deinitialized.

**SCREENSHOT:**
In this screenshot, I've opened and closed VC2 multiple times. In there you can see only the object `CustomSwitch` has stayed persistent while `CustomLabels` and `CustomSteppy` has been deallocated just as it should be.

[image: Original state]

As suggested by Rmaddy and also the reason why I wanted to create a new question is the result of the reference counts. I've followed some explanations on SO but I'm not very sure what to make out of it entirely.

[image: Reference counts (collapsed)]

[image: Reference counts]

---

**QUESTION:**
Why is this UISwitch behaving like this and how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you do what I suggested on your previous question? As a reminder that was to check the "Record Reference Counts" checkbox in Instruments and profile the app again. Then see what was maintaining a reference to each switch.

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry, yes I've done it and I forgot to add those screenshots. I'm not sure what to make out of it though as I'm really confused right now. Trying and searching to fix it but still no luck yet.

Comment: It shows the count as being +0. That means it should have been deallocated. Are you testing on a real device or the simulator? I don't trust the simulator for these sorts of things.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm testing it on iPad, iPhone and simulator. The screenshots are from tests on an iPad. If the rfcount is +0, then what does that "persistent" count means on the first screenshot? If I keep open and close VC2, the persistent bytes will keep getting higher.

Comment: @rmaddy Added deinit message for the subclasses and as expected, only the `UISwitch` doesn't print out the deinit message.

Comment: Found something else about the same issue. It seems like it's a bug... https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/842

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is (finally) fixed in iOS 10.2