# UISwitch deinit never called

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

A few days ago I've posted a problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39796709/uiswitch-not-deallocating) and I still havent found an answer for it. I think it's a bug and hope it'll be fixed in the future but can't help but think it might also be something I'm doing wrong myself.

With this question I hope to be able to confirm it's a bug so I can keep continue working on my project without worrying too much about it. If this question is repetitive, I will delete the question right away.

I have subclassed a `UISwitch` adding a `deinit` so I can see when it's getting deallocated.

```
class CustomSwitch: UISwitch { deinit {print("Switch has been deinitialized")} }
```

Then I've added a property in my view controller:

```
var customSwitch: CustomSwitch? = CustomSwitch()
```

To test it, I've added a button with the following function:

```
func removeSwitch() {
    print(customSwitch)
    customSwitch = nil
    print(customSwitch)
}
```

And the following prints out in the console:

```
Optional(<Debugging.CustomSwitch: 0x7f9ec91083c0; baseClass = UISwitch; frame = (0 0; 51 31); layer = <CALayer: 0x6100000384a0>>)
nil
```

The deinit message is not printed and in instruments it shows the customSwitch is still in memory.

The only thing I could find about this is [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/842)

Comment: I'm the only one experiencing this?

Comment: Is the switch being added to a view? if so the view retains it an its not going to go out of memory.  if you do this you should get an immediate deinit: weak var customSwitch: CustomSwitch? = CustomSwitch() because it has no strong reference.

Comment: No it's not being added to a view. Even if it was, it shouldn't matter. It's a known bug since my bug report has been marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is (finally) fixed in iOS 10.2

Answer (score -1):

According to [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Deinitialization.html), I think we can't deinit manually. It says `Deinitializers are called automatically, just before instance deallocation takes place. You are not allowed to call a deinitializer yourself.`